# Is it possible to link a string to an external database? Imagine I want to add a text and the string has to fetch the name from a database online?

Tags: database, string

```
<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="hello">hello</string>
```

can I implement it in the string .xml file or do I need a specific class in the .java file?

Comment: This question is unclear to me. Please specify how you have set up your application, which database you are using and how the .xml is linked to the .java file.

Comment: I'm sorry but this kind of question cannot be simply answered. It appears you are lacking understanding of basic concepts of programming. There is lot of learning resources online for Java and other languages. Try using some sample application and modifying it. After you learn more we welcome you back with more specific questions.

Comment: okay, say that I have a super basic layout .xml with some items to be purchased. No problems with adding images, linking them to external websites etc, but I would like to add a textview underneath each of them with the price. Though, the price is very likely to change hence why I would avoid deploying a class involving internal SQL storage.
I have either two ways: setting the text of the textview to a "dynamic" string that depends on a online resource or a GetReadableDatabase, correct? I guess the first way is the best but how can I do that?